# Laravel query builder select name

Tags: mysql, laravel

In the following:

```
DB::table('users')
    ->join('item', 'users.id', '=', 'item.user_id')
    ->select('item.name')
    ->get();
```

Is there a way to reference 'item.name' as just 'name'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. You need to use either `DB::raw` or `selectRaw`

```
select(DB::raw('item.name AS name'))
```

Or

```
selectRaw('item.name AS name')
```

Comment: If there's more than one would it look like this? selectRaw('item.name AS name', 'item.name2 AS name2')?

Comment: No. You need to pass them as string `selectRaw('item.name AS name, item.name2 AS name2')`